# Is it okay to use multiple AD network at the same time without mediation?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, unityads

I have an Android App which already has Google AdMob integrated in it, however lately i have been considering adding Unity ADS to my app as well, because Unity ADS has CPCV, which Google AdMob doesn't have, I don't want to add Unity ADS as mediation because i am not looking to display them in case AdMob doesn't have any ads, but i want two different buttons, on that displays Admob ads when clicked and the other one displays Unity ADS, i will integrate the Unity SDK as if i don't have AdMob already, can i do so? or is it against the terms of use of admob or unityADS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as many AD as you want. The only thing that can stop you is maintainability of code.